# Can somebody confirm that adobe reader works with custom content provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, adobe-reader

I have implemented a custom content provider serving pdf documents as ParcelFileDescriptor. Files are stored in the local storage marked as PRIVATE. Based on an URI the documents are then handed over to the selected pdf application.

This works for all PDF Viewer applications except adobe reader. Can someone please confirm that adobe reader does not work with content providers? Code below:

When document has been downloaded:

```
private void loadDocInReader(String doc) throws ActivityNotFoundException, Exception 
{
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(doc);   

    logger.debug("PDF Application ID is: " + pdfAppID);

    if (this.pdfAppID != null && this.pdfAppID.length() > 0) 
    {
        boolean pdfApplicationIsInstalled = checkPDFApplicationIsInstalled(this.pdfAppID);

        if(pdfApplicationIsInstalled) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setPackage(pdfAppID);
            intent.setData(uri);
            intent.setType("application/pdf");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else {
            logger.error("Please install Adobe Reader first!");
        }
    }
    else {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setData(uri);
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

All other pdf viewer apps call this method except adobe reader:

```
public class DocumentProvider extends ContentProvider 
{
@Override
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    File file = null;

    try {

        file = new File(uri.getPath());
        logger.debug("Delivering ParcelFileDescriptor for path: " + file.getPath());
        return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file,   ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        logger.error("Error loading Document: ",e);
    } finally {
        if(file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    return 0;
}
}
```

Adobe Reader always states: "Invalid File Path"

Thanks in advance!!! Kay.

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7887891/1024132

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Problem is that adobe reader does not even run through my content provider implementation. How am i passing the file to adobe reader?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can determine Adobe Reader has flaky support for reading files from ContentProviders.  In my case, the openFile method is called and returns a valid ParcelFileDescriptor, but Adobe Reader reports "The document could not be opened."  My content provider works fine with "Drive PDF Viewer", "PDF Reader" and "qPDF Reader", which are some of the top PDF viewers in the Play Store.

Adobe Reader is able to open PDF file attachments in Gmail using the Gmail content provider, but I cannot determine how or why that works.

Answer (score 0):

I has also issues with Adobe Acrobat Reader not working with my custom provider and finally got it working. My problem was that files in app-local file-space are encrypted and their names are hashed. So the `Uri` was something like:

```
content://my.app.provider/08deae8d9ea9bc0b84f94475d868351830e9f7e7
```

It works with any PDF viewer app I've tested except Adobe Reader. Today I did one last try to **add a `.pdf` extension to the Content Uri** (which is definitely not required) and when Adobe calls an `openFile()` function I strip the extension away. VOILA, it works!!!

**Update**

Please make sure that also `_display_name` column your `ContentProvider` returns as result of `query(Uri, String[], String, String[], String)` query **also contains `.pdf`** extension!!!

**Note**

Tested with **Adobe Acrobat Reader** version **16.3**

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you solved the issue.