# Exceptions from PDF readers while previewing generated PDF file on Android/PDFBox

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, pdf-generation

I am currently working on an Android app which generated a PDF file from user input. The app basically takes an empty PDF form and fills it with user input using *PDFBox* and *PDFbox-android*.

The user is provided the option to preview the generated PDF file using a PDF reader installed on the device. For testing purposes, the Android Emulator with API23 is used, and both *Adobe Reader DC* and *DocsToGo* (with PDF) has been installed on the emulator. Both apps works normally on their own, however they fail to open the generated PDF file. My question is somewhat similar to [Problems opening pdf in Android: Invalid file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887843/problems-opening-pdf-in-android-invalid-file-path), but I would rather properly use `FileProvider` to restrict access to the file as needed rather than make it public using the SDCard (or assuming there is one).

Once the PDF file has been generated into the internal storage of the app, i.e. using `getFilesDir()`, the app generates an `Intent` object with PDF readers. See the code below:

```
@Nullable
@CheckResult
public Intent createPdfIntent(@NonNull File _file,
                              @NonNull Activity _activity) {
...
pdfUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(_activity, "com.tbdsoft.pass", _file);
pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
pdfIntent.setDataAndType(pdfUri, "application/pdf");
pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

pkgManager = _activity.getPackageManager();
intentInfo = pkgManager.queryIntentActivities(pdfIntent, 0);

for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : intentInfo) {
        packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
    _activity.grantUriPermission(packageName, pdfUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    }

    if (intentInfo.size() > 0) {
        return Intent.createChooser(pdfIntent, _activity.getString(R.string.select_app));
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

As the code above shows, I'm using the `FileProvider` mechanism to give read access to the intent. As such, I have the following lines defined in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, as indicated by the `FileProvider` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html)

```
<application>
    <provider
        android:authorities="com.tbdsoft.pass"
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>

</application>
```

And the `file_paths` specifies the `paths` attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path name="forms" path="forms/" />
</paths>
```

When executing the app, I can confirm that the file is properly generated by verifying debug information within *logcat* and using the *Android Device Manager*. Downloading the generated PDF file from the emulator show no issue and actually opens properly in *Adobe Reader* and *FoxIt* on the host PC. The following log data shows the file and uri used for creating the `Intent`:

```
07-11 20:51:55.439 32653-32653/? D/com.tbdsoft.pass: Packing '/data/user/0/com.tbdsoft.pass.debug/files/forms/form_-1416209969.pdf' for PDF intent.
07-11 20:51:55.439 32653-32653/? D/com.tbdsoft.pass: Uri: content://com.tbdsoft.pass.debug/forms/form_-1416209969.pdf
```

However, both *Adobe Reader* and *DocsToGo* fails to open the generated PDF file. *Adobe* generates the following error:

```
   Process: com.adobe.reader, PID: 862
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.adobe.reader/com.adobe.reader.viewer.ARViewerActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid path: /sdcard
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid path: /sdcard
       at android.os.StatFs.doStat(StatFs.java:46)
       at android.os.StatFs.(StatFs.java:39)
       at com.adobe.libs.buildingblocks.utils.a.h(Unknown Source)
       at com.adobe.libs.services.b.a.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.adobe.reader.viewer.ARViewerActivity.enterDocumentViewing(Unknown Source)
       at com.adobe.reader.viewer.ARViewerActivity.actOnIntent(Unknown Source)
       at com.adobe.reader.viewer.ARViewerActivity.onCreateRAW(Unknown Source)
       at com.adobe.libs.d.a.f.onCreate(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
    Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: statvfs failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
       at libcore.io.Posix.statvfs(Native Method)
       at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.statvfs(BlockGuardOs.java:298)
       at android.system.Os.statvfs(Os.java:500)
       at android.os.StatFs.doStat(StatFs.java:44)
       at android.os.StatFs.(StatFs.java:39) 
       at com.adobe.libs.buildingblocks.utils.a.h(Unknown Source) 
       at com.adobe.libs.services.b.a.a(Unknown Source) 
       at com.adobe.reader.viewer.ARViewerActivity.enterDocumentViewing(Unknown Source) 
       at com.adobe.reader.viewer.ARViewerActivity.actOnIntent(Unknown Source) 
       at com.adobe.reader.viewer.ARViewerActivity.onCreateRAW(Unknown Source) 
       at com.adobe.libs.d.a.f.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

While *DocsToGo* spits out the following error (via *logcat*):

```
07-11 21:34:18.227 31919-31919/? W/ContextImpl: Failed to ensure /sdcard/Android/data/com.dataviz.docstogo/files/Documents: java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid mkdirs path: /storage/self/primary/Android/data/com.dataviz.docstogo/files/Documents
...
07-11 21:34:16.560 1588-1611/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity: +340ms (total +42m18s386ms)
07-11 21:34:17.412 1588-2305/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.tbdsoft.pass.debug/forms/form_1209803383.pdf typ=application/pdf flg=0x3000001 cmp=com.dataviz.docstogo/com.dataviz.dxtg.ptg.android.PDFToGoActivity} from uid 10067 on display 0
07-11 21:34:17.436 1588-9331/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 31919:com.dataviz.docstogo/u0a63 for activity com.dataviz.docstogo/com.dataviz.dxtg.ptg.android.PDFToGoActivity
...
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: nullform_1209803383.pdf: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
07-11 21:34:18.460 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
07-11 21:34:18.460 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:87)
07-11 21:34:18.460 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:127)
07-11 21:34:18.460 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:116)
07-11 21:34:18.461 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at com.dataviz.dxtg.common.g.b.d.(Unknown Source)
07-11 21:34:18.461 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at com.dataviz.dxtg.common.android.ToGoActivity.b(Unknown Source)
07-11 21:34:18.461 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at com.dataviz.dxtg.common.android.ToGoActivity.a(Unknown Source)
07-11 21:34:18.461 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at com.dataviz.dxtg.common.android.ToGoActivity.a(Unknown Source)
07-11 21:34:18.461 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at com.dataviz.dxtg.ptg.android.PDFToGoActivity.a(Unknown Source)
07-11 21:34:18.461 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at com.dataviz.dxtg.common.android.ToGoActivity.t(Unknown Source)
07-11 21:34:18.461 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at com.dataviz.dxtg.common.android.ToGoActivity.s(Unknown Source)
07-11 21:34:18.461 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at com.dataviz.dxtg.common.android.ToGoActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
07-11 21:34:18.461 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at com.dataviz.dxtg.ptg.android.PDFToGoActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
07-11 21:34:18.462 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
07-11 21:34:18.462 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
07-11 21:34:18.462 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
07-11 21:34:18.462 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
07-11 21:34:18.462 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
07-11 21:34:18.462 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
07-11 21:34:18.462 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-11 21:34:18.463 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
07-11 21:34:18.463 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
07-11 21:34:18.463 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-11 21:34:18.463 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
07-11 21:34:18.463 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-11 21:34:18.471 31919-31919/? W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
07-11 21:34:18.487 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
07-11 21:34:18.487 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
07-11 21:34:18.487 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
07-11 21:34:18.487 31919-31919/? W/System.err:  ... 24 more
07-11 21:34:18.500 1588-1810/? W/MountService: No primary storage defined yet; hacking together a stub
07-11 21:34:18.503 1588-2322/? W/MountService: No primary storage defined yet; hacking together a stub
07-11 21:34:18.520 31919-31919/? W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: nullattachment.pdf: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
07-11 21:34:18.521 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at com.dataviz.dxtg.common.android.ToGoActivity.a(Unknown Source)
07-11 21:34:18.521 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at com.dataviz.dxtg.common.android.ToGoActivity.a(Unknown Source)
07-11 21:34:18.521 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at com.dataviz.dxtg.ptg.android.PDFToGoActivity.a(Unknown Source)
07-11 21:34:18.521 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at com.dataviz.dxtg.common.android.ToGoActivity.t(Unknown Source)
07-11 21:34:18.521 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at com.dataviz.dxtg.common.android.ToGoActivity.s(Unknown Source)
07-11 21:34:18.521 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at com.dataviz.dxtg.common.android.ToGoActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
07-11 21:34:18.521 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at com.dataviz.dxtg.ptg.android.PDFToGoActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
07-11 21:34:18.521 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
07-11 21:34:18.521 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
07-11 21:34:18.521 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
07-11 21:34:18.521 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
07-11 21:34:18.521 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
07-11 21:34:18.521 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
07-11 21:34:18.521 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-11 21:34:18.521 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
07-11 21:34:18.521 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
07-11 21:34:18.521 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-11 21:34:18.521 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
07-11 21:34:18.521 31919-31919/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

The process used to work previously in the development stage (with other minor issues), but when implementing usage of `FileProvider` and creating a 'debug' build type, something appeared to have broken. Trying to restore things to a previous stable state didn't work out, but I might have missed some things. Adding write access (via `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION`) didn't help. Since the file is created, I do not seem to have other permission issue related to file system permission. The filenames of the forms are generated using `File.createTempFile`. Scanning the errors, its unclear to me if the apps have an issue with the `/sdcard` folder, or if somehow the uri provided is invalid.

Clearly I am doing something wrong either when creating my `Intent` or setting up my permissions. I'd like to have some pointers on things to check/try to fix this issue so I can resume testing. Any help appreciated.

Thanks